# Text out of limit of box in Css

Tags: html, css

In the follwing example the text goes out of the box. And when I reduce the size of the borowser the size of the boxes shring resposively but the text becomes mixed and unorganized. How can solve this?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>This is an email template</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgba(79, 183, 227, 0.4);
            direction: rtl;
        }
        
        body * {
            font-family: Tahoma;
        }
        
        a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-right: 25px;
            color: #46B1F9;
        }
        
        #wrap {
            background-color: #e0f2f6;
            margin: auto;
            width: 75%;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }
              
        .item {
            border: 1px solid #95A5A6;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            width: 60%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .item p {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        
        .item img {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
        }
        
        .item .notice {
            text-align: center;
            float: right;
            padding-top: 25px;
            padding-right: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            height: 1em;
        }
        /*clearfixes*/
        
        .clearfix:after {
            content: ".";
            display: block;
            height: 0;
            clear: both;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        
        .clearfix {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
        
        * html .clearfix {
            height: 1%;
        }
        
        .clearfix {
            display: block;
        }
        /* End hide from IE-mac */
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div style="padding:15px;">

            <div class="item clearfix">
                <div class="notice">
                    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam rhoncus sollicitudin aliquet. Fusce dolor leo, egestas non nisi in, aliquam ullamcorper diam. Quisque placerat tortor in porta egestas. Aenean et elementum purus. Nunc eget nulla blandit, volutpat libero non, finibus purus. Vivamus vitae tellus at risus commodo varius.</p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://s14.postimg.org/wqzq39iht/image.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="item clearfix">
                <div class="notice">
                    <p>
                        <strong>اLorem ipsum</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam rhoncus sollicitudin aliquet. Fusce dolor leo, egestas non nisi in, aliquam ullamcorper diam. Quisque placerat tortor in porta egestas. Aenean et elementum purus. Nunc eget nulla blandit, volutpat libero non, finibus purus. Vivamus vitae tellus at risus commodo varius.</p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/y4kk17q21/image.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="item clearfix">
                <div class="notice">
                    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam rhoncus sollicitudin aliquet. Fusce dolor leo, egestas non nisi in, aliquam ullamcorper diam. Quisque placerat tortor in porta egestas. Aenean et elementum purus. Nunc eget nulla blandit, volutpat libero non, finibus purus. Vivamus vitae tellus at risus commodo varius.</p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/xca6ju1kj/image.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Think you're stuck with [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) and [min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) to keep the bounding boxes bigger than their content.  That or scrollbars as ProllyGreek suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to expand the block by content, removing height from  `.item .notice` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases your text will overflow the box , so you should add `overflow:scroll` to `notice` class

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to do.

If the boxes must be a fixed height there are couple of different strategies.
The easiest thing to do is to turn off the height restriction to the `notice` class.  However, this will reflow your document and push everything down.

On the other hand, if you want to keep the current layout, I cannot provide you a unilateral decision as the padding, height and overflow will conflict with each other on this element.